# Why ItemSkippedException?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, apache-commons

I am trying to update content in Google sites and am reading the stream in exception VersionConflictException.

When I check the stream it is all fine and is completely loaded in POST request but then I get following error.

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream$ItemSkippedException
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:880)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaSource$Output.writeTo(MediaSource.java:87)
at com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaBodyPart$MediaSourceDataHandler.writeTo(MediaBodyPart.java:74)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:452)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:157)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.output.media.MediaMultipartGenerator.generate(MediaMultipartGenerator.java:58)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.output.media.MediaMultipartGenerator.generate(MediaMultipartGenerator.java:37)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.writeRequestData(Service.java:1831)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.updateMedia(MediaService.java:497)
at com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaEntry.updateMedia(MediaEntry.java:159)
at morefile.UploadApp.updateAttachment(UploadApp.java:136)
```

Comment: hey, iam also looking for the same. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 8):

**FileItemStream.ItemSkippedException**

> This exception is thrown, if an
>   attempt is made to read data from the
>   InputStream, which has been returned
>   by FileItemStream.openStream(), after
>   Iterator.hasNext() has been invoked on
>   the iterator, which created the
>   FileItemStream.

Comment: exception is thrown in   
    while (it.hasNext()) and the stream is used in catch. How does it come back to hasnext once it has moved on to catch is a mystery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to wake the zombies  - this is just for future reference.

This is a basically a bad implementation of the `apache-commons-fileupload`. Calling `hasNext()` should **NEVER** render the result of the last `next()` call invalid. E.g. you can't do something like this

```
List collection;
while(hasNext(){
   Object o = next();
   collection.add(o);
}
```

Because if you access any item in the list it will result in an `ItemSkippedException`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I found it was caused by calling 'Streams.asString( stream)' twice. Reviewing the file upload source code, Streams.asString() will close the stream at the end of its operation, so if you call it again with the same stream, which is InputStream obtained from FileItemStream.openStream() by the way, you will get this exception. Fixed my program, and it works now as I intended!

Answer (score -1):

I used to get this when I used to close the stream during iteration. Don't close the stream and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what was happening to me. I was getting this error because I had added

```
FileItemStream.openStream()
```

to the "Add Watch" in Intellij Idea, which is why it was throwing me this error. 
Don't add this to watch while debugging.